# Erase pixels in a Polygon in a Huge Raster Dataset in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap

I've a huge raster dataset and I have to replace a small portion with new data. I tried several things to remove related area to upload new raster but I couldn't have any success.

I'll try ArcPy solutions if there will be any.

Things I have tried are:

1. First run Math > "Greater than" tool with specific extent to find a extract area. Then Set Null to extract this raster from original, but somehow I can't get whole raster, just the area I'm working on with "NoData".
2. I tried to read all data in Python with arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray() but the size of data was a problem. I tried to work with the area related, but again converting array to raster is the same area instead of the whole raster.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question. The two things you tried could each be the subject of a separate question. For a question about ArcPy please include a code snippet that illustrates what you tried exactly.